# nodejs express + create-react-app oauth2.0 error 401 'Invalid access token' Spotify API

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, create-react-app, spotify

I'm trying to build an app that allows me to call Spotify's API from a `create-react-app` client through a `nodejs express` server. I'm trying to use the [Authorization Code Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow).

It works getting the authorization code using the following code to generate the URL, completely on client side (if and how using server-side is another question):

```
getSpotifyCodeUrl() {
  const authEndPoint = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize'
  const clientId = CLIENT_ID;
  const responseType = 'code';
  const redirectUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/';
  // TODO: state for cross-site request forgery protection
  // cont state = '...';
  const scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email';
  return(
    authEndPoint +
    '?response_type=' + responseType +
    '&client_id=' + clientId +
    (scope ? '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(scope) : '') +
    '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(redirectUrl)
  )
}
```

The user simply clicks a link with the href as generated above.

```
{!this.state.token ? <a className="btn btn--loginApp-link" href={this.getSpotifyCodeUrl()}>
  Login to Spotify
</a> : ""}
```

After the user gets redirected back, I use the following function to extract the authorization code from

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({code: new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('code')});
}
```

With the code I retrieve the access token. Call from client:

```
getSpotifyAccessToken() {
  fetch('/auth?code=' + this.state.code)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({token: data.token});
      localStorage.setItem('token', this.state.token);
    });
}
```

API call on server:

```
app.get("/auth", (req, res) => {
  let code = req.query.code;
  let authOptions = {
    url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    form: {
      code: code,
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/',
      grant_type: 'authorization_code'
    },
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer.from(clientId + ':' + clientSecret).toString('base64'))
    },
    json: true
  };

  request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body){
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      token = body.access_token;
      res.json({ token: "Token: " + body.access_token});
    } else { 
      console.log("/auth response body")
      console.log(body) 
    } 
  });
});
```

Strange thing is I get a token, but can also see the following error in my server terminal:

> {
> error: 'invalid_grant',
> error_description: 'Invalid authorization code'
> }

If I then try to use the token to do a (simple) request from client:\

```
getSpotifyMe() {
  fetch('/me?token=' + this.state.token)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

And corresponding server call:

```
app.get("/me", (req, res) => {
  let token = req.query.token;
  console.log("Token: " + token);
  let options = {
    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token },
    json: true
  }

  request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log("/me request body");
    console.log(body);
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      res.json(body);
    } else {
    } 
  })
})
```

Which gives me a 401 error:

> { error: { status: 401, message: 'Invalid access token' } }

I've tried some things. Doing the call from client, no success. Refreshing tokens, deleting cookies, authorizations from account, but no success. The strange thing is I can use the token said to be invalid in the [Spotify Web Console](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-current-user/), doing the exact same call I'm trying to do in the application.

Do you know where I'm causing these errors (invalid_grant and 401) in my application? And how I could solve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following [the example on Spotify GitHub](https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples/tree/master/authorization_code) more closely.

I changed my `create-react-app` to simply call the `/login` server route. Don't use fetch like I tried, you'll end up with a cross-origin error once the server calls the Spotify API from a different origin. For some unapparent reason I can't use `href="/login"`, the server simply doesn't respond, but that's fruit for another SO question.

```
<a href="http://localhost:3001/login">Login to Spotify</a>
```

The server index.js is now simply the Authorization Code Flow `app.js` with my own variables and one minor tweak.

- My `redirect_uri` is `http://localhost:3001/callback`, I struggled long and tiresome with redirecting back to my client `create-react-app` at `http://localhost:3000`, perhaps this is where something goes wrong with the auth code and access token, IDK. You wanna go straight into the **server-side** callback. Much more intuitive for the user as well: one click and bam, logged in, no messy redirects in between.
- In the `/callback` route on the server, when the `access_token` and `refresh_token` have either been successfully retrieved or not, that's when you want to redirect back to your client, `http://localhost:3000` for me. With the tokens of course. The example uses URL params, I'm guessing setting a cookie should also work, but have to do some research if that's a security no-go.

The small little tweak I made is to the CORS clause for the app. There's no need for incoming request at the server other than coming from my client, so I added a `{origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}` there, just in case.

```
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../client/build'))
    .use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}))
    .use(cookieParser());
```

That's it, works like a charm, I can see the response body of the `/v1/me` call coming in at the server (there's a console log in the example code) and tokens are coming back to the client.